# Conda mysql package not recognized in any python interpreter

Tags: python, conda, mysql-connector

I've looked at other similar issues, but all my paths seem to be fine. I tried to install the python mysql library in conda so I could use it. To all metrics, it seems installed and recognized in the Pycharm interpreter, and when running `conda list`, I see `mysql` as an installed library, yet any time I try to import it, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. See below for a sample:

[image]

To isolate the issue,  I chose to install another well known package that was not previously on my env, `tenserflow`, here's the results of that:

[image]

Evidently the issue is with the `mysql` library, since `tensorflow` installed and functioned as expected, meaning this isn't an issue with the interpreter, or an incorrect python path, or probably even conda.

I'm at a loss to what the issue is. I have mysql server installed, though that shouldn't matter, and I only have one environment. I'm trying to connect to a db, and have never used any mysql libraries on Python, so if there's others can be recommended, I have no preference, I just want my db!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really want this https://pypi.org/project/mysql/ library? This seems a proxy of https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/ which was last updated 6 years ago. and if you really need it i think it should be `import MySQLdb` doc here https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#id11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only installed the c library `mysql`, not the python library that you were looking for.

You need to do

```
conda install -c conda-forge mysql-connector-python
```

which will install the `mysql` python module that you are looking for